# Firefox: compile error "'ascii' codec can't encode character"

Tags: python, firefox, compilation

I try to compile Firefox because, i had made some changes. But when i try to compile the stuff, i get this error:

```
   Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 483, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/ternes3/Downloads/mozilla-release/testing/mozbase/mozprocess/mozprocess/processhandler.py", line 698, in _processOutput
    self.processOutputLine(line.rstrip())
  File "/home/ternes3/Downloads/mozilla-release/testing/mozbase/mozprocess/mozprocess/processhandler.py", line 663, in processOutputLine
    handler(line)
  File "/home/ternes3/Downloads/mozilla-release/python/mach/mach/mixin/process.py", line 86, in handleLine
    line_handler(line)
  File "/home/ternes3/Downloads/mozilla-release/python/mozbuild/mozbuild/mach_commands.py", line 242, in on_line
    self.log(logging.INFO, 'build_output', {'line': line}, '{line}')
  File "/home/ternes3/Downloads/mozilla-release/python/mach/mach/mixin/logging.py", line 54, in log
    extra={'action': action, 'params': params})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1191, in log
    self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1246, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1256, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1293, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 740, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ternes3/Downloads/mozilla-release/python/mozbuild/mozbuild/mach_commands.py", line 75, in emit
    self.fh.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 98: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My build system is ArchLinux 64bit. My changes based on Firefox 25 Source. I have change only design stuff no code.

Answer (score 1):

The code in question essentially just logs something to stdout. It seems that your stdout (Terminal?) isn't utf-8 or a similar known-to-python encoding. Try setting your [`locale`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale) to something sensible, preferably something utf-8.

You may check the stdout encoding python will use by e.g. executing `python -c "import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this at the beggining of your script :

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```